# List of elements per category within for loop

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a case, where on my template view I would like to display list of all objects (Issues) and categories (Sprints). I already applied also another filtering to display Issues that belongs to particular Project.

I've managed so far to display Sprints and within each Sprint I am displaying list of issues. How can I apply additional filtering on issues, that only issues belongs to particular sprint will be displayed?

Final result should be to display list of all issues divided per sprint.

My code below:

```
    #views.py
    class ProjectBacklogView(DetailView):
        model = Project
        template_name = 'project-backlog.html'
        context_object_name = 'backlog'

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(ProjectBacklogView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['project'] = Project.objects.all()
            context['issue'] = Issue.objects.all().order_by('sprint')
            # context['epic'] = Epic.objects.all()
            # context['initiative'] = Initiative.objects.all()
            context['sprint'] = Sprint.objects.all()
            return context

    # template.html
    {% extends 'base-project.html' %}

    {% block content %}
    {% for sprint in backlog.sprint_set.all %}
    <h4>{{ sprint.name }}</h4>
            <div id="simpleList" class="list-group" style="margin-bottom: 2%;">
                    {% for issue in backlog.issue_set.all %}
                    <div class="list-group-item">
                            <div style="float:left;"><strong><a href="{% url 'issue-edit' issue.pk %}">{{ issue.title }}</a></strong></div>
                            <div style="float: right;"><a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-circle btn-sm"><i class="fas">{{ issue.remaining_estimate }}</i></a></div>
                            <br /><br /><hr style="border-top: dashed 1px;"></hr>
                                <div style="float: left;"><small>Assignee: <strong>{{ issue.assignee }}</strong></small></div>
                                <div style="float: right;"><small>Initiative: <strong>{{ issue.initiative }}</strong></small></div><br />
                                <div style="float: left;"><small>Priority: <strong>{{ issue.priority }}</strong></small></div>
                                <div style="float: right;"><small>Epic: <strong>{{ issue.epic }}</strong></small></div>

                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <br />
            </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}

#models.py
class Project(models.Model):
    PROJECT_TYPE = (
        ('SCR', 'Scrum'),
        ('KAN', 'Kanban'),
    )
    # slug = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    alias = models.CharField(max_length=8, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=160)
    project_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=PROJECT_TYPE, default="SCR")
    lead = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

# Definicja nazwy modelu w Adminie Django
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('project-detail', args=[str(self.alias)])

class Sprint(models.Model):
    # sprint_type = models.TextField(default='Sprint', editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    goal = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Issue(models.Model):
    ISSUE_PRIORITY = (
        ('Critical', 'C'),
        ('High', 'H'),
        ('Medium', 'M'),
        ('Low', 'L'),
    )
    issue_type = models.TextField(default='Issue', editable=False)
    issue_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    # slug = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    initiative = models.ForeignKey(Initiative, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    epic = models.ForeignKey(Epic, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sprint = models.ForeignKey(Sprint, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    priority = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=ISSUE_PRIORITY, default='Medium')
    assignee = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='assignees', null=True, blank=True) # zczytywane z tabeli userów
    author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='authors') # zczytywane z tabeli userów
    remaining_estimate = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default='0') # w minutach
    time_logged = models.IntegerField(default='0') # w minutach
    attachment = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True) # To Do - multiple files??

    def __str__(self):
       return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('issue-detail', args=[str(self.issue_id)])
```

My issue is I don't know how to apply dynamically filter (based on field sprint) as sprints are listed in `for loop`

Comment: Can you show your models? It seems the relationship is between Backlog and Issue, how is Issue related to Sprint?

Comment: @DanielRoseman - Backlog is only a view in my code. I updated my original post by adding models.py